# Roughness on 3D extension of a 2D border

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, 3d-printing

I am working on a project where we are investigating the effect different shaped drum borders have on the sound the drum makes. It is relatively easy to do the mathematical calculations with different shaped borders, and in actuality, we can do them with almost any simple closed curve defined as the border that has a parametrization. Obviously we would like to compare our calculations with real world experiments, and so we would like to 3D print the borders we are using in Mathematica so that they can be the same shape.

Right now, I have a function that produces a 3D-printable object using `ParametricPlot3D[]`:

```
(* x,y are the HEADS of the parametric functions *)
print3Dborder[{{x_, y_}, {umin_, umax_}}, height_, thickness_] :=
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[u], y[u], z}, {u, umin, umax}, {z, 0, height},
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[thickness], PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, Boxed->False,Axes->False]
```

e.g Unit Circle: `print3Dborder[{{Cos,Sin},{0,2Pi}},0.05,0.05]` produces
[image]

The difficulty is when I try to create a border for a more sharply curved border. `ParametricPlot3D[]` seems to be creating extra bumps and points around the edges, extruding further into the z-direction. (I made an oddly shaped border by interpolating over a shortest tour of 5 random points in [-1,1]x[-1,1])

e.g The code

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 2}];
fst = FindShortestTour[pts];
ordered = pts[[fst[[2]]]];
ptsrepeat = Join[ordered, ordered[[2 ;; 5]]];
intx = Interpolation[ptsrepeat[[All, 1]], Method -> "Spline"];
inty = Interpolation[ptsrepeat[[All, 2]], Method -> "Spline"];
GraphicsColumn[{
  ParametricPlot[{intx[u], inty[u]}, {u, 3, 8}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{intx[u], inty[u], z}, {u, 3, 8}, {z, 0, .05},
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[.06], PlotPoints -> 100, Boxed -> False,
   Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]
}]
```

Produces

[image: Sideview of Oddly Shaped Border]

It is difficult to see them since they are so small relative to the rest of the object, but when I export it as a `.stl` file for my 3D printer, they remain and cause problems in the printing process.

Ideally, it would look like (from the side):

[image]

Any ideas on how to smooth these 3D objects out is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Why do your points appear twice in the interpolating function? Isn't it enough to make sure that the first and last points are the same?

Comment: Yes it is. To be honest, I was just trying different things to see if I could smooth out the function before extending it to three dimensions.